# Regex to replace wiki citation in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

What would be the regex to replace citations in Wikipedia article?

Example Input:

```
 text <- "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas "
```

Expected Output:

```
"just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas"
```

I tried:

```
> text <- "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas "
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all(text, "\\[ \\d+ \\]", "")
[1] "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas "
```

Comment: A double back slash is needed to escape`[`. So this works fine: `stringr::str_replace_all(text, "\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\s*", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
trimws(sub("\\[.*\\]", "",text))
```

Result:

```
[1] "just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas"
```

This pattern looks for an opening bracket (`\\[`), a closing bracket (`\\]`) and everything in between(`.*`).

By default `.*` is greedy, that is, it will try to match as much as possible, even if there are closing and opening brackets until it finds the last closing bracket. This match gets substituted by an empty string.

Finally, the `trimws` function will remove the spaces at the star and end of the result.

**Edit: Erasing citations throughout the sentence**

Should there be citations at several points in the sentence, the pattern and function changes to:

```
trimws(gsub(" ?\\[.*?\\] ", "",text))
```

For example, if the sentence was:

```
text1 <- "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism [34] regards the Vedas "
text2 <- "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism[34] regards the Vedas "
```

The respective results would be:

```
[1] "just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas"
[1] "just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas"
```

Pattern changes:

`.*?` will change the regexp from greedy to lazy. That is, it will try to match the shortest pattern until it finds the first closing bracket.

The starting `?` (space + question mark) this will try to match an optional space before the opening bracket.

Comment: This seems to be simplest answer. Better to use `gsub` instead of `sub`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
text <- "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas "
 library(stringr)
 str_replace_all(text, "\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\s*", "")
```

Output:

```
 "just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas "
```

Answer (score 3):

This regex would be one option:

```
(?!.*\]).*
```

The lookabout ( block inside parentheses) will greedy set the pointer after the last "]" . The rest of the expression ".*"  will match what you want ( including the leading space // but that will be an easy one in your language of choose ) up to the new line

Answer (score 0):

Your `\\[ \\d+ \\]` does not work since there are spaces in the pattern. Moreover, if you remove the spaces, the expression will only match `[`+`digits`+`]` and will not match `[note 7]`-like substrings.

Here is a Base R solution using `gsub` with a TRE regex (no `perl=TRUE` is necessary):

```
text <- "[76][note 7] just like traditional Hinduism regards the Vedas "
trimws(gsub("\\[[^]]+]", "", text))
## Or to remove only those [] that contain digits/word + space + digits
trimws(gsub("\\[(?:[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]*)?[0-9]+]", "", text))
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/xHsR3e)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\\[` - a literal `[` (must be escaped outside a char class)
- `(?:[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]*)?` - (an optional sequence due to `?` quantifier at the end) 1 or more alphanumerics followed with 0+ spaces or tabs
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `]` -  a literal `]` (no need escaping outside a character class)

The `trimws` removes leading/trailing whitespace.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW5xF5/1) (note the PCRE option is chosen since it supports POSIX character classes, do not use this site for testing your TRE regular expression patterns!).